# Python: append() and extend()

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a .txt file of 3 million rows. The file contains data that looks like this:

```
# RSYNC: 0 1 1 0 512 0
#$SOA 5m localhost. hostmaster.localhost. 1906022338 1h 10m 5d 1s
# random_number_ofspaces_before_this text $TTL 60s
#more random information
:127.0.1.2:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/domain/$
test
:127.0.1.2:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/domain/$
.0-0m5tk.com
.0-1-hub.com
.zzzy1129.cn
:127.0.1.4:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/domain/$
.0-il.ml
.005verf-desj.com
.01accesfunds.com
```

I am trying to parse it such that it looks like:

```
+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|    domain_name     | period_count | parsed_code |                      raw_code                       |
+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| test               |            0 | 127.0.1.2   |  :127.0.1.2:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/domain/$ |
| .0-0m5tk.com       |            2 | 127.0.1.2   |  :127.0.1.2:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/domain/$ |
| .0-1-hub.com       |            2 | 127.0.1.2   |  :127.0.1.2:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/domain/$ |
| .zzzy1129.cn       |            2 | 127.0.1.2   |  :127.0.1.2:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/domain/$ |
| .0-il.ml           |            2 | 127.0.1.4   |  :127.0.1.4:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/domain/$ |
| .005verf-desj.com  |            2 | 127.0.1.4   |  :127.0.1.4:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/domain/$ |
| .01accesfunds.com  |            2 | 127.0.1.4   |  :127.0.1.4:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/domain/$ |
+--------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

To that end, I have come up with the following:

```
rows = []
raw_code = None
parsed_code = None
with open('dbl-sr-2019-06-02T23_38_27Z.txt', 'r') as f: # assumes the file name is input.txt
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        if line.startswith(':127'):
            raw_code = line
            parsed_code = re.split(":", line)[1]
            continue
        if line.startswith('#'):
            continue
        rows.append((line, parsed_code))
#         rows.append((raw_code))
#         rows.extend((line, parsed_code, raw_code))
#         rows.extend((raw_code))

import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['domain_name', "parsed_code" 'raw_spamhaus_return_code'])
print(df)
```

The commented out lines in the code chunk above either, did not produce the output I wanted, or gave an error. I am struggling to build a Pandas dataframe with more than 2 columns. I can get `domain_name` and one other column. It seems I am unable to get the code down to correctly use the `.append` and `.extend` functions. Can someone please provide guidance?

Comment: Why is that in your current implementation, the `rows` only has 2 columns while the `len(df.columns)` is 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The likely source of your problem is a missing comma.

This:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=[
    'domain_name', 'parsed_code', 'raw_spamhaus_return_code'])
```

is not the same as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=[
    'domain_name', "parsed_code" 'raw_spamhaus_return_code'])
```

because (note the missing comma):

```
"parsed_code" 'raw_spamhaus_return_code'
```

becomes one string.

#### Test Code:

```
import re

data = [x.strip() for x in """
    # RSYNC: 0 1 1 0 512 0
    #$SOA 5m localhost. hostmaster.localhost. 1906022338 1h 10m 5d 1s
    # random_number_ofspaces_before_this text $TTL 60s
    #more random information
    :127.0.1.2:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/domain/$
    test
    :127.0.1.2:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/domain/$
    .0-0m5tk.com
    .0-1-hub.com
    .zzzy1129.cn
    :127.0.1.4:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/domain/$
    .0-il.ml
    .005verf-desj.com
    .01accesfunds.com
""".split('\n')[1:-1]]

rows = []
raw_code = None
parsed_code = None
for line in data:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    if line.startswith(':127'):
        raw_code = line
        parsed_code = re.split(":", line)[1]
        continue
    if line.startswith('#'):
        continue
    rows.append((line, line.count('.'), parsed_code, raw_code))

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=[
    'domain_name', 'period_count ', 'parsed_code',
    'raw_spamhaus_return_code'])
print(df)
```

#### Results:

```
         domain_name  period_count  parsed_code  \
0               test              0   127.0.1.2   
1       .0-0m5tk.com              2   127.0.1.2   
2       .0-1-hub.com              2   127.0.1.2   
3       .zzzy1129.cn              2   127.0.1.2   
4           .0-il.ml              2   127.0.1.4   
5  .005verf-desj.com              2   127.0.1.4   
6  .01accesfunds.com              2   127.0.1.4   

                            raw_spamhaus_return_code  
0  :127.0.1.2:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/doma...  
1  :127.0.1.2:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/doma...  
2  :127.0.1.2:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/doma...  
3  :127.0.1.2:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/doma...  
4  :127.0.1.4:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/doma...  
5  :127.0.1.4:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/doma...  
6  :127.0.1.4:https://www.spamhaus.org/query/doma...
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you edit your answer to show me how to count the periods in `domain_name`? I know it will look something like: `period_count = line.count('.')`, which I can't get to work exactly (it counts 5 for every line)